# Is captcha needed if a submit request is posted through ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, captcha, bots, spam

If I use an ajax request to post a form without actually creating any form or input elements on the page, is a `captcha` still needed to block `spambots`?

Are there any `spambots` out there clever enough to run JavaScripts and submit a ajax post?

Comment: Anybody can post to the same URL without using AJAX.

Comment: captcha is never *needed*.

Comment: I have used a similar technique to yours, not having an `action` attribute in the form but submitting it via AJAX to a url kept in my JS code. In my experience, this has a very high rate of preventing spam. But obviously you'll never get rid of all - and the worst spam was actually sent in by real people anyway ;)